# Swap two fieldsets by jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have Div tage and within have 2 fieldset tags. I need after checking conditions in document ready event, call function for swap them .I mean fieldset 2 come up fieldset1 .

please note this sample :

```
      <div id='InformationDiv'>

         <fieldset id='fieldset1'>
              ...
              ...
         </fieldset>

         <fieldset id='fieldset2'>
              ...
              ...
         </fieldset>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve with these snippets:

```
    $("#InformationDiv fieldset:first").insertAfter($("#InformationDiv fieldset:last"));
```

Above script will work always even if you want to make swap many times.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use,

```
$(function() {
    // check for condition

    // swap elements
    $("#fieldset1").before($("#fieldset2")); //put fieldset1 before fieldsset2
    //Or
    $("#fieldset2").before($("#fieldset1")); //put fieldset2 before fieldsset1
});
```

Similarly you can try using `.after()`, `.insertBefore()`, `.insertAfter()`